# Wait the end of a function before to start the next

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, async-await, es6-promise

I'm working on Ionic v4 with Angular.

In my project i use the BLE to communicate with a raspberry.

I have several step :

1. Search Device around me
2. Connect to this device
3. Activate Notification
4. Send Messages

Currently i have something like :

```
this.ble.scan().subscribe(result => {
  if (device === theDeviceIWant) {
    this.ble.connect(device.id).subscribe(result => {
      this.ble.startNotification(infosaboutDevice).subscribe(result => {
        // Message 1
        this.ble.writeWithoutResponse(infos, message).then(result => {
          // Message 2
          this.ble.writeWithoutResponse(infos, message).then(result => { 
            // Message 3
            this.ble.writeWithoutResponse(infos, message).then(result => {
              // Message X
              this.ble.writeWithoutResponse(infos, message).then(result => {
              })
            })
          })
        })
      })
    })
  })
}
```

I want to do something like that :

```
this.myScan();
this.myConnect();
this.myNotification();
this.myMessage('Text 1');
this.myMessage('Text 2');
this.myMessage('Text X');
```

The probleme : My function ‘myConnect‘ don't wait the end of ‘myScan‘ to start. So somme stuff needed by ‘myConnect‘ is do in ‘myScan‘.

I already try to use ‘async/await‘ but does not work. I think i don't use it correctly :

```
 await this.myConnect().then(async () => {
       await this.myNotification().then(async () => {
           await this.myMessage('03020000').then(async () => {
               await this.myMessage('010100').then(async () => {
                   await this.myMessage('020200' + this.random.toString(16));
               });
           });
       });
   });
```

Help me to understand how to create a function who wait the end of the before one to start :D

Comment: Your last block of code looks completly strange (and can be simplified to what I posted in my answer), but it should actually even do what you want. So I think your actual problem is in the implementations of myXXX functions. You probably don't return the "right" promise there. Can you show a full example that is not working?

Answer (score 5):

Just use async/await OR `then`

```
 await this.myConnect();  // this awaits the Promise returned by myConnect to be resolved
 await this.myNotification();  // same for this Promise
 await this.myMessage('03020000');  // and so on...
 await this.myMessage('010100');
 await this.myMessage('020200' + this.random.toString(16));
```

Answer (score 2):

> The keyword await makes JavaScript wait until that promise settles and
>   returns its result.

So you dont need to use `then` in `await this.myConnect().then(()=>{});`

use `await this.myConnect()`;

Below is example which help you understand better

```
function SignalOne() {

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(()=>{
                resolve('Hello iam signal one');
            }, 2000);
        });

    }

    function SignalTwo() {

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(()=>{
                resolve('Hello iam signal Two');
            }, 1000);
        });

    }

    async function sendSignal() {
        let one = await SignalOne();
        let two = await SignalTwo();
        console.log(one);
        console.log(two);

    }

    sendSignal();
```

Comment: I have this code : https://pastebin.com/VGSfJhqn 
Why my bleconnect is reject ?

In my console i saw the 'BLE : reject'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
async myScan() {
   // do things
}

ngOnInit() {
   const scan = this.myScan(); // myScan doesn't actually have to return here
   await scan;
   const connect = this.myConnect();
   await connect;
   // more stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially what Promises are made for.

> A Promise is an object representing the eventual completion or failure
>   of an asynchronous operation.

[You can read up about Promises here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises). Once you read thru that, I left an example for you below to demonstrate how to use a `Promise`:

```js
//Wrap the operation you want to wait for in a Promise (in this case: setTimeout)
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve('3 seconds have passed');
  }, 3000);
});

//Once the operation is resolved the callback in the .then will be called
promise.then(val => document.querySelector('#target').innerHTML = val);
```

```html
<div id="target">This message will change once the operation is resolved in 3 seconds.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would embrace Observables. Looking at what you want..

1. Search Device around me
2. Connect to this device
3. Activate Notification
4. Send Messages

1 and 2 would be chained with [`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html), as responses depend on each other. Then 3 and 4 could be performed in order, but not dependent on each other, therefore we could use [`concat`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/concat.html) with those. (If this is not correct flow, adjust accordingly with these two operators).

So I suggest the following:

```
import { never } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap, concat } from 'rxjs/operators';

// ...

this.ble.scan().pipe(
  switchMap((device) => {
    if (device === theDeviceIWant) { 
      return this.ble.connect(device.id)
    }
    // terminates rest of code
    return never();
  }),
  concat(
    this.ble.startNotification(...),
    this.ble.writeWithoutResponse(...)
  )
).subscribe(data => console.log(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're so close! Rather than using `.then` *and* `async` just use one or the other. Here are a few ways to accomplish what you are trying to do:

### Using `.then`:

This is your typical chaining syntax. Promises can be chained using `.then()` and passing in a function. If the return value is a value (not a `Promise`) then it will resolve to that value. But if it *did* return a `Promise` then it will chain together and your next `.then()` will resolve to the "inner" async call result.

```js
// Message 1
return this.ble.writeWithoutResponse(infos, message).then(result1 => {
  // Message 2
  return this.ble.writeWithoutResponse(infos, message);
}).then(result2 => { 
  // Message 3
  return this.ble.writeWithoutResponse(infos, message);
)}.then(result3 => {
  // Message X
  return this.ble.writeWithoutResponse(infos, message);
}).then(result4 => {  })
```

### Using `async`/`await`

This approach achieves the same result but uses special keywords to automatically chain promises together. `async`/`await` allows you to skip the `.then()` and `return` calls so you can invoke your async functions as if they were synchronous.

```js
// Message 1
let result1 = await this.ble.writeWithoutResponse(infos, message)
// Message 2
let result2 = await this.ble.writeWithoutResponse(infos, message);
// Message 3
let result3 = await this.ble.writeWithoutResponse(infos, message);
// Message X
let result4 = await this.ble.writeWithoutResponse(infos, message);
```

To learn more about `Promise`'s and async javascript, check out these resources:

- [Promises on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)
- [Promises on Google Web Fundamentals](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises)
- [Video on Async/Await](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vn3tm0quoqE)